# Stud hole for Romex electrical wire filled with Green-glue acoustic sealant - Cause of concern?

Tags: electrical, wire, sound-proofing, fire-hazard, sealant

I am helping my brother with his unfinished basement when I realized he made a mistake. I told him to use a fire stopping sealant in certain stud holes where Romex wire was being fed through.

Unfortunately he used the wrong sealant, he used saint-gobain's acoustic soundproof sealant (i.e: Green-Glu).

My primary concern was "Would there be a negative reaction from the soundproof sealant coming into contact with the Romex sheathing" *(i.e: Would it damage the sheathing or is there any serious risk)*

I reached out to Saint-Gobain for more information and couldnt get a straight answer ***(which is  understandable)***

*Saint Gobain - "We do not have any information on using with wires and I don’t expect our sealant will provide an acoustical function in contact with the wires, and it could be a safety issue if a fire develops in one cavity as this is not a fire blocking material."*

I plan on trying to remove some of the sealant and replace with a fire stopping sealant but there are areas I simply don't have access to. To anyone's knowledge is there any serious risks here? Should I be concerned with the Romex Sheathing having any negative reactions to the sealant?

Its worth nothing:
- The only "official" reported negative reaction I could find is when it comes into contact with copper. They also state it can be used around plastic junction boxes.

- [Green Glu Material Datasheet](https://acousticalsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/as-green-glue-noiseproofing-sealant-msds.pdf)
- [Product Used](https://acousticalsolutions.com/product/green-glue-noiseproofing-acoustical-sealant/)

Comment: I don't think there will be any reaction, but fire-proof sealants are usually used where they are required by code, so if you didn't use them in a code-required place it seems like that would be the primary concern (won't pass an inspection).

Comment: Fire stopping in studs or going up / down through plates? A photo may be helpful.

Comment: @EdBeal - Let me know if this makes sense or if I made it worst:

http://evanwowk.com/clao_new/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/ImageOfGluOnStud.png

Comment: Ok I can see the sub floor one as being needed , the horizontal one? What’s on the other side of that stud ? Garage or living space then it would need sealing.  Horizontal runs don’t normally need sealing unless they connect multiple rooms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MDS notes that the components are latex polymer, water and CaCO3 (calcium carbonate). These are inert and should not interact with the sheathing.

[image]

Comment: 1~ week test. Although testing a little over a week is no real "timeframe" Ack is correct. The components are inert and initial looks showed it had no negative effects on the romex.

I was able to peel it off the romex with no issues at all. I am going to assume other then the issues discussed above there is no serious harm in this.